# Multi-line headers for TTabSheet?

Tags: windows, delphi

I have a TPageControl with several tabs. On one page, the header is a bit too long and appears clipped on a single line. Is it possible to have the tab header be multi-line (ie. like the WordWrap property on buttons)?

In the image below the caption has been set to "This text is too long to fit onto one row". Ideally, this should appear on two rows:

```
This text is too long to fit
onto one row
```

For the example below I have set:

```
TabWidth := 185;
TabHeight := 60;
```

[image: Labels on one line only]

*** EDIT ***

The example above does not apply any theme. When a skin is applied (in this case the 3rd party product VCLSkin) and I insert a newline character at runtime, then it works:

```
Product_Sheet.Caption := (
    'This text is too long' + #13#10 + 'to fit onto one row');
```

[image: With skin applied]

Based on the comments below, this suggests that in the absence of a skin, this will need to be custom-drawn.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this at all. Your page control looks nothing like mine. I'd guess that the answer will be found in the code that you are running that we know nothing of, the code that draws those tabs in non-standard fashion.

Comment: The page control is not being drawn in any fancy way. What I have done is set TabHeight to "60" (rather big), and manually added a red rectangle just for the example image. The caption for the 1st sheet is `Remote Support` and so on.

Comment: Well, it's the `TabWidth` property that you set that is important. Leave `TabHeight` and `TabWidth` at their default values of `0` and all is good. You should add a manifest too so that you get a themed app. Your program is about 15 years behind the times in terms of appearance.

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using? And what version of Windows?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Setting `TabWidth` to `0` dynamically resizes each tab to the exact width of the header text. While related, this is an answer to a different question. I like having a fixed width for each tab, but where the caption exceeds the available width to spread that over two rows. Of course, it might not be possible...

Comment: @JerryDodge: Delphi7 on WES (embedded version of Windows XP). Is this feature available on later versions of Delphi or Windows?

Comment: Well there you go. Windows is responsible for such drawing, and if none of us are able to reproduce this issue in any other version of Windows, it must be this particular version of Windows which does not draw it as desired.

Comment: Actually now that I tested on Delphi 10 Seattle on Windows 8.1, I have the precise issue you're speaking of. I'm not sure how @DavidHeffernan managed to get around it.

Comment: @JerryDodge I reproduced it once I realised that Alain was changing the properties of the page control. An [mcve] would have been useful.

Comment: @AlainD I think that if you insist on fixed width and height then you'll have to take over drawing the text. That's not hard and there are plenty of examples around to show you how to do so. If you run on an embedded system then I guess you don't want themes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I've updated the question with the missing details for `TabWidth` and `TabHeight`, apologies for the misunderstanding. Correct themes are not generally required, but the user can apply a skin...and when I apply a skin, I get the behaviour I need! Looks like this is something I'll have to custom draw myself (if a skin is not applied). Thanks for the input.